# Is it possible to destroy Tkinter widgets by pathname?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have several widgets created in a loop, each given a sequential name, eg:

```
for item in itemlist:
    myWidget=tk.Widget(root, name=item)
    myWidget.pack()
```

Now I have widgets with pathnames like

```
.!mainapplication.!itemframe.item1
```

is it possible to use the pathname to destroy a widget?

I can't use `myWidget.destroy()` because then I can't target specific widgets.

If it's not possible I can create an array to hold the widgets and deal with them from there, but I was wondering if there was any way to do it this way.

Comment: Try `root.nametowidget('.!mainapplication.!itemframe.item1').destroy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the return value of `tk.Widget(...)` to a list or dictionary, you can access any of the widgets without having to use the name. This is by far the most common and convenient way to manage widgets created in a loop.

Example:

```
widgets = []
for item in itemlist:
    myWidget=tk.Widget(root, name=item)
    myWidget.pack()
    widgets.appen(widget)
...
for widget in widgets:
    widget.destroy()
```

If you really need to convert a name to a widget, tkinter provides a method on every widget called `nametowidget` which accepts the name of a widget and returns the instance.

```
root.nametowidget('.!mainapplication.!itemframe.item1').destroy()
```

Comment: I've used lists to keep track of variables before, but since I'm already assigning the names from another list, it seemed a lot easier to me to just continue using it's assigned name, instead of creating a whole other list. Thank you for your response.